# HDD Toshiba or Western digital for install PS4 games?

Tags: hard-disk

I will to install PS4 games in a USB 2.5 HDD.  Which HDD is better: 
[Toshiba Canvio Basics 1TB](https://www.worten.es/productos/informatica/discos-duros/externo/disco-duro-portatil-1-tb-toshiba-canvio-basics-negro-5405533) or [Western Digital Elements 1TB](https://www.worten.es/productos/informatica/discos-duros/externo/disco-duro-portatil-1-tb-wd-elements-negro-5122440)? I'm thinking in speed and durability.

Comment: SSD all the way.  Samsung 840/850  Faster, more reliable,less power, and etc.

Answer (score 1):

SSD is your best choice for top notch performance. If storage is your higher priority then go for magnetic disks.

Answer (score 0):

They look identical with different manufacturers only. If you found the RPM differences I could tell you a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

They both look identical. Neither give information on the drive used in the enclosure. You might want to have an external drive that's either 1: has a drive with 7200RPM or an SSD for even more speed.

https://www.wdc.com/products/portable-storage/wd-elements-portable.html#WDBUZG0010BBK-NESN

If you have the money: [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-T3-Portable-SSD-MU-PT1T0B/dp/B01AVF6UO8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AVF6UO8).